# Intuition to move-optimality in Sokoban

Tags: soft-question, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

The puzzle game of [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) has been fascinating to me since I was a child. It is played on a rectangular grid. Each square may be empty ( ) or contain a wall (`#`), a box (`$`), the pusher (`@`) , a box on a goal (`*`) or the pusher on a goal (`+`).
The player controls the pusher, where a single step is either up (`u`), down (`d`), left (`l`) or right (`r`). The pusher can push single boxes if the square behind is empty or a goal (indicated by uppercase letters in the notation). Wall squares are forbidden for both the pusher and boxes.

The number of boxes equals the number of goal squares, and the aim is to push all boxes to a goal square. The game is mathematically interesting as it is computationally very hard (PSPACE-complete) and indeed, there are very challenging problems already on pretty restricted grid sizes. Common metrics on the solutions are the number of moves and the number of pushes. (Often enough, there is no solution which is both move- and push-optimal.) For human intuition, push-optimality is easier to grasp than move-optimality.

I have been trying to improve my understanding of move-optimality. Let me start with a very easy example.

```
   ###
 ###@#
 #   #
## $ #
#.   #
######
```

Many people will start to approach the box in a straight move, resulting in the 8-move solution `ddLulDrdL`. However, it can be done in 6 moves by `dlDrdLL`. Why does the second approach result in a shorter solution? The reason is that one should avoid unnecessary changes of direction while pushing a box around, since each such change involves two "empty" moves to relocate the pusher. The first solution has two direction changes, while the second one has only one, so consequently the first solution takes two more moves than the second one.

Now look at the following only slightly more involved example.

```
########
#  @ ..#
# $  ###
# $  #
#    #
######
```

Most people will solve this box by box, which might result in the 25-move solution `lldRRdrUluRRlldddlUUluRRR` or `llddRRdrUUluRRllddlUluRRR` (note that for the second box, we pick the path minimizing the direction changes as learnt in the first example). However, with a further switch of the pushed box, a 23-move solution can be found `llddRUluRRRRldddlUUluRR`.

I'm struggling to find a satisfactory understanding why that results in a shorter solution. The best thing I can come up with is something like "it is costly to get behind the boxes, so when doing that investment, try to get done as many things as possible from that spot". However, this argument is somewhat diffuse and it is not hard to design a level where the same reasoning won't result in an improvement.

Can anyone give some better higher-point-of-view intuition/explanation of the improvement? Is there some useful metric/invariant (like the number of direction changes in the first example)?

---

EDIT: Let me try to give an alternative formulation of what I'm hoping for: From example 2, I got the vague understanding that in certain situations it may be helpful to push different nearby boxes "in one sweep" towards the goal squares. But most of the time I have no idea if in the end it will actually make a difference or not. So I'm looking for better insight or some heuristic which allows me to get a higher confidence of the final outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your basic intuition/explanation for the second problem is correct: try to move as many boxes as possible in one sweep. The fact that there are games where this doesn't always work should not be surprising. Despite the seeming simplicity of this game, theoretically there are an almost infinite way the game pieces can be placed for a particular puzzle, and given the placement of the walls, what works in one situation may lead to a dead end in another. In fact, this is exactly what makes it an interesting puzzle game.

So, I really don't think you can ever come up with hard rules that allow for no exceptions. Therefore, 'rules' like 'minimize the number of switches' and 'move as many boxes with one sweep' will be fairly good heuristics to find an efficient solution, but you really should not expect any of these rules to always apply for the most optimal solution.

Comment: True, it's pretty clear that "hard rules that allow for no exceptions" won't exist (at least as long as they are computable in reasonable time). What I want is to improve my intuition by understanding some small examples. And given my feeling that the "in one sweep" heuristic is too fuzzy, I simply don't want to accept that the second example in my question is already too large for that...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the moves codified by strings, and you need a way to rank these strings of same length in a way to compare which one is "easier" as game, I think a good metric could be using the [Kolmogorov Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) for these arrays, since will gives a non-arbitrarily way to weight how difficult they are as a game, thinking here, in ranked them on how hard would be to memorize each of them string to use them as "cheat codes", for example, on an imaginary game of PS1 (yes, I am old hahaha), remember a string of 6 movements R-L1-L-U-R1-L1 is harder than U-D-U-D-U-D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Frankly, I don't think that the analysis of the solution strings will be of much help. The optimality of a string heavily depends on the structure of the surrounding maze (walls, boxes), which is only partially covered by the solution string.

Comment: @azimut As an idea of how you can use the Kolmogorov Complexity: since in every move you have a finite number of alternatives, for each play your alternatives will expand as a decision tree... to explore the tree, you can use it as a "score function" to choose more simplest branches and drop the more complex ones, and example I know works good for these kind of trees is the [A-star algorithm (A*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), maybe you can implemented with the Kolmogorov complexity as the "Heuristic" function.